# Can you show that one form of the solution is the following: Sec 2π/17 = (2+√17+√W-√Y) /2

Tags: puzzle, polygons

It is known that Sec2π/17  radians is a root of the equation:
x8 -8x7 - 40X6  +  80X5  + 240X4  -192X3 - 448X2 +128x + 256   =  0
where X= Sec 2π/17.   This is associated with the regular 17-sided polygon.
This equation can be solved algebraically. Can you demonstrate this?
Can you show that one form of the solution is the following:
Sec 2π/17  = (2+√17+√W-√Y) /2  ,  where W=17+4√17 ,  Y=2(17+2√17+4√W-√Z) ,
and Z=17-4√17.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the nicer form of this comes from taking $2 \cos \frac{2 \pi}{17}$ in the form  $\omega + \omega^{-1},$ where $\omega$ is a primitive 17th root of unity; taking the long factor out of $ \frac{x^{17} -1}{x-1}$ as zero leads to
$$ x^8 + x^7 - 7 x^6 - 6 x^5  + 15 x^4 + 10 x^3 - 10 x^2 - 4x + 1 . $$
Writing it using only square roots is still a mess. It is done in Galois Theory by David A. Cox.

[image]